# Factors and Dummy Variables in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am new to data analytic and learning R. I have few very basic questions which I am not very clear about. I hope to find some help here. Please bear with me..still learning -

I wrote a small function to perform basic exploratory analysis on a data set with 9 variables out of which 8 are of Int/Numeric type and 1 is Factor. The function is like this :

```
  out <- function(x) 
  {
    c <- class(x)
    na.len <- length(which(is.na(x)))
    m <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    s <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    uc <- m+3*s
    lc <- m-3*s
    return(c(classofvar = c, noofNA = na.len, mean=m, stdev=s, UpperCap = uc, LowerCap = lc))
  }
```

And I apply it to the data set using :

```
stats <- apply(train, 2, FUN = out)
```

But the output file has all the class of variables as Character and all the Means as NA. After some head hurting, I figured that the problem is due to the Factor variable. I converted it to Numeric using this :

```
train$MonthlyIncome=as.numeric(as.character(train$MonthlyIncome))
```

It worked fine. But I am confused that if without looking at the dataset I use the above function - it wont work. How can I handle this situation.

When should I consider creating dummy variables?

Thank you in advance, and I hope the questions are not too silly!

Comment: Try `stats <- sapply(train, FUN = out)`. `apply` converts your data.frame into a matrix, which can hold only one data type.

Comment: Your second question is more difficult to answer. You need dummy variables for modeling, but most model functions can do the dummy encoding automatically for you.

Comment: `sapply` worked, but the factor variable gave NA, I think I'll need to convert it to numerical first. Thanks.

Comment: What is the standard deviation of a factor? How does it make sense to coerce a factor to numeric and calculate the sd from this?

Comment: Oops..My bad!! Actually the MonthlyIncome in my dataset is a factor variable - which it shouldn't be. That's why I said I need to convert it into the numerical type first. Thanks @Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `c()` results in a vector and all element within the vector must be of the same class. If the elements have different classes, then `c()` uses the least complex class which is able to hold all information. E.g. numeric and integer will result in numeric. character and integer will result in character.

Use a list or a data.frame if you need different classes.

```
out <- function(x) 
  {
    c <- class(x)
    na.len <- length(which(is.na(x)))
    m <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    s <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    uc <- m+3*s
    lc <- m-3*s
    return(data.frame(classofvar = c, noofNA = na.len, mean=m, stdev=s, UpperCap = uc, LowerCap = lc))
  }
```

`sum(is.na(x))` is faster than `length(which(is.na(x)))`

Use `lapply` to run the function on each variable. Use `do.call` to append the resulting dataframes.

```
stats <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(train, out)
)
```

Comment: I used the `sum(is.na(x))` in the code and I added `data.frame` as suggested but now am not able to use the function in `apply` or `sapply`. I am getting the following error   _Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame_  Am not sure how to resolve this.